# swift ios how to check fields in core database

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

how do i check the fields in my core database and also if i wanted to add an entity how would it be possible? below is my code for saving the data , i wanted to add other data aside from name into my core db table using the key groceryitem.

```
 func saveItemInLocalDB(groceryItem : Item) {
        let context = getContext()

        //retrieve the entity that we just created
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "GroceryItem", in: context)

        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        //set the entity values
        item.setValue(groceryItem.name, forKey: "name")
        item.setValue(false, forKey: "isSelected")
        item.setValue(loggedInUserHouseNumber, forKey: "houseNo")

        //save the object
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("ang item:", groceryItem.name)
            print("saved!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   let IsFeildAvailable = entity.attributesByName.keys.contains("keyname")

    if IsFeildAvailable
    {
        print("Key/field is exist")

    }else{
        print("Key/field does not exist")
    }
```

Comment: and if i wanted to add new one Sir?

Comment: Do you want to add a field?

Comment: yeah2 i wanted to add new field